# Installing Cordova plugin in Cordova 2.6

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Can someone please explain how to add a plugin?

I added the m and h files to Plugins directory

Then in config.xml  add the line:

```
<plugin name="DeviceDetails" value="DeviceDetails" />
```

and included the js file in my html

[image: Plugin in the project]

How do I actually use this plugin now? And how do I know it works?

I currently am doing: (coffeescript)

```
        try 
            console.log DeviceDetails()
        catch e
            console.log e
```

and get this error in xCode:

```
[LOG] {"line":24,"sourceURL":"file:///var/mobile/Applications/31C9E766-02DF-4C7E-8B32-9588F394F427/Flight.app/www/media/js/index.js","stack":"onDeviceReady@file:///var/mobile/Applications/31C9E766-02DF-4C7E-8B32-9588F394F427/Flight.app/www/media/js/index.js:24\nfire@file:///var/mobile/Applications/31C9E766-02DF-4C7E-8B32-9588F394F427/Flight.app/www/cordova-2.6.0.js:683\n@file:///var/mobile/Applications/31C9E766-02DF-4C7E-8B32-9588F394F427/Flight.app/www/cordova-2.6.0.js:221\n[native code]"}
```

This is the plugin js file:

```
;(function(cordova) {

    function DeviceDetails() {}

    DeviceDetails.prototype.getDetails = function(callback) {
        cordova.exec(callback, callback, "DeviceDetails", "getDeviceDetails", [])
    }

    DeviceDetails.prototype.getUUID = function(callback) {
        cordova.exec(callback, callback, "DeviceDetails", "getDeviceUUID", [])
    }

    if (!window.plugins) window.plugins = {}
    window.plugins.deviceDetails = new DeviceDetails()

})(window.cordova || window.Cordova || window.PhoneGap);
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin architecture needs updating for use with Cordova 2.6.0.

But you can just use Phonegap's own Device API ([see here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_device_device.md.html)) to get the same information without needing a plugin.